# Running WinSCP script displays nothing

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I'm trying to use WinSCP through script to synchronize a local folder with an FTP one.

I created a script a below

```
open ftp://<user>:<pw>@ftp.myserver.com/initFolder/
synchronize remote -delete C:\Data\backup /initFolder/
exit
```

And I run it with the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /log="C:\data\bin\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /script="C:\data\bin\myScript.txt"
```

However, it appears nothing is happening. The command exists immediately with no message (either error or some processing / confirmation, etc).

Also no log file is created either.

What am I doing wrong?

Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, with the command-line syntax you are using, WinSCP runs without any GUI.

If you are starting WinSCP from a console window (e.g. from Windows batch file or PowerShell), [use `winscp.com` instead of `winscp.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables). `winscp.com` is a console application. You will see any errors in the console.

Alternatively, you can add [`/console` switch to `winscp.exe` command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) to make it open its own console window. Though you will rarely want this.